# Calculate the intersection of two matrix kernels in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, nullspace

If we have a discrete saddle point problem with the coefficient matrix
$$ \mathcal{A} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
   A & B^T \\
   B & 0
 \end{bmatrix},
$$
then $\mathcal{A}$ is invertible, supposing $B$ has full rank and $A$ is positive semidefinite (which hold in my case), if $\mathrm{ker}(A)\cap\mathrm{ker}(B) = \{0\}$. The basis for the kernel or null space of a matrix can be calculated by `null(A)` in MATLAB. But how should I interpret mathematically and calculate the intersection of the two kernels?

Comment: Please don't sign your posts.

Comment: I cannot even do that.

Comment: I removed your signature at the end of the post "Thanks,
Zoltán"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB, null([A; B]) will find an orthogonal basis for the intersection of the null spaces of A and B.

It seems unlikely that you really want to find this basis, but it's not clear from your question what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: I really wanted to find that, because if this is empty, then it means that $\mathcal{A}$ is invertible. Unfortunately, in my code, this is not empty. You are clear, the question was subtle. I am doing domain decomposition using the TFETI method. After prescribing all the constraints, $\mathcal{A}$ should be regular. So I do not want to directly use the inverse, I just wanted to calculate it for debugging purposes.